# maven. Is deployed (remote) but older SNAPSHOT version takes precedence over more recent installed (local) when --update-snapshots is used?

Tags: maven, snapshot

It is clear that `--update-snapshots` option makes maven download SNAPSHOTs from artifactory, but what if I have more **recent** version built and installed in .m2 locally?

Comment: That more recent version should win.

Comment: Can you exactly tell use what you mean by more recent version is meant? Can you show how your version looks like something `1.2-SNAPSHOT` vs. `1.3-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: they both look like 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT, but local version was `mvn install`-ed after previous 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT was `mvn deploy`-ed